# Problem with export data from excel to R (not interpreting data as numbers)

Tags: r

I have the following problem with exporting data from excel, and importing them into R.

My data in excel contains "," so excel interprets them as numbers.

But when I have this data in R I have "." so R interprets them as text instead of numbers.

For example,

In excel I have 12,765 and in R I have 12.765

Do you have any idea how can I fix this ?

I use the following code to import the data file into R:

```
library(openxlsx)
read.xlsx("pk.xlsx")
```

Comment: To be clear: Is the number in your example meant to be 12765 (twelve thousand and a few hundreds) or 12.765 (twelve and a bit)?

Comment: When you say that "My data in excel contains "," so excel interprets them as numbers."... are you sure about that? What is the "Number Format" for this column? It should tell you in the text box above the $ % , buttons in the "Number" tab of the Home menu of Excel.

Comment: Often the easiest way is to export from Excel to a CSV file. Then import using `read.csv(filename, dec=",")` or using `dec="."`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the nice package `readxl` from the tidyverse (https://readxl.tidyverse.org/) :

```r
library(readxl)
read_excel("pk.xlsx")
```

Your should find everything you need with the `tidyverse` to import different format of files (`readr` for all csv, tsv and so on... ).